# node.js - precision about code execution path

Tags: mysql, node.js, asynchronous, io

I have been reading that node.js is single-threaded and synchronous. However, I/O requests are performed asynchronously [[1]](http://blog.mixu.net/2011/02/01/understanding-the-node-js-event-loop/).

I have a question. Given the following code snippet:

```
c.query(  //#1
'SELECT SLEEP(20);',  //#2
    function (err, results, fields) {
      console.log("query executed"); //#3
    }
);
console.log("hello"); //#4
```

Assume there are 2 requests in the queue. My understanding is as follows: The first request does this path #1->#2->#4->#3. After that the second request is processed.

From what I have been reading, it seems the author is implying #1->#2->#4. Since #3 is asynchronous (waiting for I/O), the second request is processed in the meantime.

Could anybody clarify on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node.js event flow is based on callbacks, that are asynchronous.

In this way, even if Node.js is single threaded, when you call a function that takes a callback, that function is called asynchronously, without blocking the execution of the synchronous code.

In the example you've inserted you can see that the *query* function accepts a callback as last parameter. Once it is called, Node.js sends the execution on the event flow, proceeding to the next line of code.

To clarify, in that example there's no #2 path, `'SELECT SLEEP(20);'` is the first parameter of the query function. The second parameter is the callback function `function (err, results, fields) {}` executed when the query function returns a result.

The flow will be #1->#3->#2:

```
c.query('SELECT SLEEP(20);',//#1
    function (err, results, fields) {
        console.log("query executed"); //#2
    }
);
console.log("hello"); //#3
```

Comment: Since #1 makes the mysql database sleep for 20s, #1->#3->#2 means that #2 is executed after 20s. Then #1 blocks the execution, right?

Comment: Not really. We are talking about the execution flow of node.js. If you make something like 'SELECT SLEEP(20000)' your db will sleep for 20 seconds, but node.js will not be blocked and will continue to execute the next lines of code. The other logic depends on the application you're building.

Comment: So if #3 takes a long time, then we can assume the path can become #1->#2->#3?

Comment: Sorry, i made a mistake in pasting the code. #2 is async. It will always been executed after #3, doesn't matter how long it takes.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. Thanks!